# Navigation Drawer Android List Item Hight

Tags: java, android, xml

I made a custom drawer for an android application but there is a problem that the first Item's hight is bigger than all other items.. My XML code of Navigation Drawer is:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- other Layouts here -->

  <!-- My custom list here -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#F3F3F4"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" >
    </ListView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The ListView Custom adapter layout code is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#efefef" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc_list_item_icon"
        android:src="@drawable/logout_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:textColor="@color/list_item_title"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivAeroo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/rightorangearrowicon" />
     <View
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="#ababab" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My Layout still making first item Large like this..
[image: See Home Hight as compare to others]

Answer (score 1):

Check the images that you are using for the ImageView (id = icon).

I am pretty sure they are not all the same size.

Comment: you are right actually Icon had transparent space around it which was making its size Large :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

Instead of

```
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

for ImageView with id = icon